# SwiftUI custom alignment pushes views wider than parent

Tags: alignment, swiftui

I start with this. Some UI with two sliders.

[image]

Defined by this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num1: Double = 0.5
    @State private var num2: Double = 0.5
    let blueGreen = Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle().fill(blueGreen).border(Color.blue, width: 1.0).padding(4.0)
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Value:")
                    Slider(value: $num1, in: 0...1)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Opacity:")
                    Slider(value: $num2, in: 0...1)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.border(Color.green, width: 1.0).padding()
    }
}
```

I want the "Value:" and "Opacity:" labels to be aligned on their trailing edge, leaving the sliders lined-up and the same width. I've heard that custom alignments can align Views like this, Views that are not siblings.

So I add the custom alignment:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum MyAlignment : AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[.trailing]
        }
    }
    static let myAlignment = HorizontalAlignment(MyAlignment.self)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num1: Double = 0.5
    @State private var num2: Double = 0.5
    let blueGreen = Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle().fill(blueGreen).border(Color.blue, width: 1.0).padding(4.0)
            VStack(alignment: .myAlignment) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Value:").alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { d in d[.trailing] }
                    Slider(value: $num1, in: 0...1)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Opacity:").alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { d in d[.trailing] }
                    Slider(value: $num2, in: 0...1)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.border(Color.green, width: 1.0).padding()
    }
}
```

It partly works. The trailing edges of the labels are aligned, but now the UI has moved partly off screen to the right.

[image]

With UIKit and auto layout, I would constrain the trailing edges of those two labels to be equal. That would not push anything off screen (assuming things were constrained to screen edges, as usual). What is going wrong here? And how do you achieve this with alignments, or by some better way, with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is using Preferences (learn more [here](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/)).

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num1: Double = 0.5
    @State private var num2: Double = 0.5
    @State private var sliderWidth: CGFloat = 0

    private let spacing: CGFloat = 5
    let blueGreen = Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle().fill(blueGreen).border(Color.blue, width: 1.0).padding(4.0)

            VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                HStack(spacing: self.spacing) {
                    Text("Value:")
                        .fixedSize()
                        .anchorPreference(key: MyPrefKey.self, value: .bounds, transform: { [$0] })

                    Slider(value: $num1, in: 0...1)
                        .frame(width: sliderWidth)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)


                HStack(spacing: self.spacing) {
                    Text("Opacity:")
                        .fixedSize()
                        .anchorPreference(key: MyPrefKey.self, value: .bounds, transform: { [$0] })

                    Slider(value: $num2, in: 0...1)
                        .frame(width: sliderWidth)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)

            }
            .backgroundPreferenceValue(MyPrefKey.self) { prefs -> GeometryReader<AnyView> in

               GeometryReader { proxy -> AnyView in
                    let vStackWidth = proxy.size.width

                    let maxAnchor = prefs.max {
                        return proxy[$0].size.width < proxy[$1].size.width

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let a = maxAnchor {
                            self.sliderWidth = vStackWidth - (proxy[a].size.width + self.spacing)

                        }
                    }

                    return AnyView(EmptyView())

                }
            }

            Spacer()

        }.border(Color.green, width: 1.0).padding(20)
    }

}

struct MyPrefKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [Anchor<CGRect>]

    static var defaultValue: [Anchor<CGRect>] = []

    static func reduce(value: inout [Anchor<CGRect>], nextValue: () -> [Anchor<CGRect>]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I adapted this a bit to set the label widths and leave the sliders out of it, and hide the `.backgroundPreferenceValue` block behind a reusable `.setWidth(MyKey.self, $widthBinding)` modifier. I suspect this is not the way they intended "Preferences" to be used, but you've found a great way to get around the current shortcomings of SwiftUI.

Comment: I chose to set the width of the slider, because setting the width of the labels based on the width of the labels might be a recipe for trouble. Should SwiftUI change the order in which it calls closures and refreshes views in the future, I wouldn't be surprised if that creates some kind of loop.

Comment: @kontiki this could be solved by defining PreferenceKey.Value as dictionary with Key  uniquely assign for each View (aka tag)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I agree that Apple seems forgot to give us something in SwiftUI with/from autolayout engine, like content hugging priority, resist compression, equal sizes, etc...

In SwiftUI alignment guides does not change view sizes they just shift views "as is" aligning to specified anchor points (expanding container if it is not limited in size, because by default it tights to content, that is what you see). So to solve considered situation it needs somehow to limit (or change) sizes.

The code below is not complete solution (it does not take into account possible l10n), but shows direction - as `Slider` does not have default size, it should be limited some how to not expand container.

I would consider below as workaround, anyway... (calculations of width might be more accurate and complex, like get frame of Text, eg. via anchor preferences, and then subtract from available geometry proxy width taking into account padding, but that is still the same - specify view frame width explicitly).

[image]

```
struct HueSaturationView : View {
    @State private var num1: Double = 0.5
    @State private var num2: Double = 0.5
    let blueGreen = Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6)
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            VStack {
                Circle().fill(self.blueGreen).border(Color.blue, width: 1.0).padding(4.0)
                VStack(alignment: .myAlignment) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Value:").alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { d in d[.trailing] }
                        Slider(value: self.$num1, in: 0...1)
                            .frame(width: gp.size.width * 2/3)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Opacity:").alignmentGuide(.myAlignment) { d in d[.trailing] }
                        Slider(value: self.$num2, in: 0...1)
                            .frame(width: gp.size.width * 2/3)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .border(Color.green, width: 1.0).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You said: "In SwiftUI alignment guides does not change view sizes they just shift views 'as is' aligning to specified anchor points". Did you find this in documentation or WWDC talk somewhere? Or are you basing that on what you have observed working with SwiftUI? Because, theoretically, it would be possible for it to satisfy the alignment, like a constraint, and *then* calculate (or re-calculate) view sizes. Hard to know when they don't document anything!